# ansible tower_project module, always getting "ansible-tower-cli required for this module"

Tags: ansible

I have a control host that has the following:

- ansible --version = 2.5.2
- tower-cli --version == 3.3.0

tower-cli is able to connect to a remote Ansible Tower instance (note, Ansible tower itself is not installed on this control host).  Can run 'tower-cli user list' on control host and works as expected.

However, when I try to use a playbook with the tower_* modules, such as:

```
  tasks:
  - name: create the SCM project
    tower_project:
      name: "test project"
      state: present
      ...
```

Always getting the following:

> ansible-tower-cli required for this module

Any ideas, as I can use tower-cli just fine on this localhost that is running the playbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the origin of the issue, and unless someone else had run into it they wouldn't have known where to look --

check details of `tower-cli --version` and `ansible --version`, as well as `which tower-cli` `which ansible`;  in my case were installed in *different* python environments:

> /usr/lib/python**2.6**/site-packages/ansible
>
> /usr/lib/python**3.4**/site-packages/tower_cli

If you cannot see the python version using the above for tower-cli, you can run:

```
$ head -n1 `which tower-cli`
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
$
```

The ansible modules couldn't see the tower_cli python modules as they were in a different python environment.

After-the-fact problem origin:  I had installed **`ansible` via `yum`** (package manager), and **`ansible-tower-cli` via `pip`** (python installer).  Being consistent in how you install both to make sure they go to the same environment resolves the issue.

*Centos/RHEL*: `yum install ansible ansible-tower-cli`

-OR-

*Python*:  `pip install ansible`

*Python*:  `pip install ansible-tower-cli`